# getting native system32 on 64 bit os with inno setup running in 32-bit setup mode

Tags: inno-setup

i have a DLL which should be installed as 32 bit AND 64 bit when setup running on 64 bit OS.
I like to have Is64BitInstallMode no defined, so setup running in 32 bit mode.
My problem: {sys} returns same as {syswow64}. So my setup does not copy the 64 bit version of
the dll into native system32 folder on 64 bit os.

How can i achieve that - even running in 32 bit install mode - on a 64 bit os a 32 bit binary
is copied to {syswow64} and its 64 bit pendant copied to real-{sys} (so native 64 bit system32 folder).
Thank you

Comment: See http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=32vs64bitinstalls

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about Inno Setup, but maybe this can help:  32-bit processes on Win64 systems can access the true System32 directory by using the "sysnative" alias.  So if you can convince InnoSetup to write the 64-bit DLL to "C:\Windows\sysnative", it should end up in the real "C:\Windows\System32". (Of course, you'll need to handle the situations where the system is installed somewhere other than "C:\Windows").

Documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187.aspx

Comment: thank you for this answer. it worth a try. but it seems to start with vista. i'd like the setup running from >= xp

Comment: This is a solution that works:

Source: "my.dll"; DestDir: "{sys}"; Check: IsWin64; Flags: 64bit 

flag 64bit forces on 64 bit system ,even in 32 bit install mode, to map {sys} to native system32 folder.
Not sure, if this really works below < vista, as inno setup may uses "sysnative" as suggested by Mr. Burr

Comment: @user947604 It would be nice of you to post this as an answer (if you're still on SO). `Source: "my.dll"; DestDir: "{sys}"; Check: IsWin64; Flags: 64bit flag` get's the job done to copy the 64bit dll to System32 and vice versa.